# How to use SQL to count the occurrence of groups and treat two different columns as a unsorted set?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Given the table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    thing_a VARCHAR2(15),
    thing_b VARCHAR2(15)
);
```

And the rows

```
INSERT INTO foo (thing_a, thing_b) VALUES 'red', 'green';
INSERT INTO foo (thing_a, thing_b) VALUES 'red', 'green';
INSERT INTO foo (thing_a, thing_b) VALUES 'green', 'red';
INSERT INTO foo (thing_a, thing_b) VALUES 'red', 'blue';
```

I would like to get the result

```
green,red: 3
blue,red: 1
```

In other words, I would like to count the occurrence of each group of thing_a and thing_b, but I want to consider "red" and "green" to be the same as "green" and "red".

The closest I've come to a "solution" is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
    CASE WHEN thing_a < thing_b
    THEN thing_a || thing_b
    ELSE thing_b || thing_a END
) as thing FROM foo;
```

Which yields:

```
greenred
bluered
```

So it does the grouping correctly, but it doesn't count anything.

Any suggestions for how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, almost there. Simply wrap up the `case` query in a derived table and then `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select thing, count(*)
from
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN thing_a < thing_b THEN thing_a || thing_b
           ELSE thing_b || thing_a
           END as thing
    FROM foo
) dt
group by thing
```

Too make sure no items like ab and cde and confused with abcd and e, add a comma between the columns. (Thanks to mathguy for pointing this out!)

```
select thing, count(*)
from
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN thing_a < thing_b THEN thing_a || ', ' || thing_b
           ELSE thing_b || ', ' || thing_a
           END as thing
    FROM foo
) dt
group by thing
```

Alternatively, do a `UNION ALL` in a derived table, and `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select ta, tb, count(*)
from
(
    select thing_a as ta, thing_b as tb from foo where thing_a <= thing_b
    union all
    select thing_b, thing_a from foo where thing_a > thing_b
) dt
group by ta, tb
```

ANSI SQL compliant and portable!

Comment: @AugustLilleaas - I see you marked this answer as "correct", which is surprising considering your experience. Suppose you have the following unordered sets in your data: `('ab', 'cde')` and `('abcd', 'e')`. This solution will treat them as the same.

Comment: @mathguy, oops... What can I say... Seems like an easy edit to add a comma between the a and b things. Check back in a minute.

Comment: This will not work if the strings themselves contain commas.

Comment: @mathguy, I know, but OP has no commas or other odd characters in the sample data. Anyway, the last UNION ALL/GROUP BY query has no problem with commas.

Comment: Good point! I forgot to mention that my data conforms to `^A-Z$` (they're all three letter upper case codes), and my actual solution ended up doing what jarlh proposed here - adding a comma to separate them.

Answer (score 1):

This can be all done in a single `SELECT` statement - group by least value, greatest value. Note: This will not work if there may be `null` in either column; if that is a possibility, then the query must be written with a little more care to handle it.

```
with
     foo ( thing_a, thing_b ) as (
       select 'red'  , 'green' from dual union all
       select 'red'  , 'green' from dual union all
       select 'green', 'red'   from dual union all
       select 'red'  , 'blue'  from dual union all
       select 'ab'   , 'cde'   from dual union all
       select 'abcd' , 'e'     from dual union all
       select 'cde'  , 'ab'    from dual
     )
-- end of test data; SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select least(thing_a, thing_b) as thing_a, greatest(thing_a, thing_b) as thing_b,
       count(*) as cnt
from   foo
group by least(thing_a, thing_b), greatest(thing_a, thing_b)
order by thing_a, thing_b   --   if needed
;

THING_A THING_B CNT
------- ------- ---
ab      cde       2
abcd    e         1
blue    red       1
green   red       3

4 rows selected.
```

Comment: That's very interesting, I didn't know you could use functions in group by! I don't have null in my data so this would work just fine.